# 187GB used on fresh install

Tags: server

just installed ubuntu on a server and it shows that i have 187.96 GB used, 3.58 TB total on webmin. it doesn't look normal? i have no idea where 187.96 GB is coming from. is the system reserving a % of the total?

please assist.

Comment: Can you remove old log files in /var/log? It might be something to check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 5% are reserved, but these are not part of the "used" number.

The file system overhead on a 4 TB disk is significant and is counted towards "used", which explains part of it. To see how much space is taken by data, run `du -xsk /`, which will make a summary, counted in [KiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte).

Comment: is there a simple solution to reduce the reserved size to allow other apps to utilize it?

Comment: Sure, but you should not reduce it too far. If the disk is so full that only the reserved space is left, everything but essential services like logging and authentication starts to fail. If the reserve is also used up, these fail as well.